# Parsing serial data read in from USB using Python

Tags: python, pyserial

I am completely new to python.

I am using the following code to draw data from a USB device, which is printing data to my raspberry Pi using printf(). I am using the following python code to read this data and print it to screen:

```
 #!/usr/bin/python
    import serial
    ser = serial.Serial(
    port='/dev/ttyUSB0',\
    baudrate=115200,\
    parity=serial.PARITY_NONE,\
    stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE,\
    bytesize=serial.EIGHTBITS,\
    timeout=0)
    print("connected to: " + ser.portstr)
    ser.write("help\n");
    while True:
    line = ser.readline();
    if line:
        print(line),
    ser.close()
```

the code prints the following result as is expected (this is what I'm using printf() for):

```
Received Ticks are: 380 and nodeID is: 1
```

How can I parse the line variable so that I can save the number of Ticks (380) and nodeID (1), to two variables so that I can use those variables for a HTTP POST request in python?

Comment: regex or simple string splitting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

split the string, then take the parts you want:

```
>>> s = "Received Ticks are: 380 and nodeID is: 1"
>>> s.split()
['Received', 'Ticks', 'are:', '380', 'and', 'nodeID', 'is:', '1']
>>> words = s.split()
>>> words[3]
'380'
>>> words[7]
'1'
>>>
```